# Sql query - how to create column in table

Tags: mysql

I have in Msql database several tables with lots of rows and columns in them. I need to create a new column in one of these tables.

**How do I create an SQL query for inserting a new column in a specific table
via PhpMyAdmin?**

Answer (score 5):

```
alter table table_name add column new_column int after id
```

In my example I have added a new column that has data type int after id column. Very easy.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD columnName columnType;
```

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE people ADD hometown VARCHAR(50);
```

You can use this query in phpMyAdmin by going to the SQL tab after selecting your database.

Also, you may use the graphical user interface to add a column by following the steps:

- Select the database on the left side of the screen
- Select the table on the left side of the screen
- Go to the "Structure" tab
- Under the list of all existing columns, you have the option to add new fields (columns)

Answer (score 0):

Simple google revealed [this](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/sql_add_column.htm) and [this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/378/add-a-column-to-an-existing-mysql-table/)

```
ALTER TABLE contacts ADD email VARCHAR(60);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD [COLUMN] col_name column_definition [FIRST | AFTER col_name ]
```

Link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 0):

The command is ALTER TABLE, you can find the details [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php)